# Use ffmpeg to stream VP8 encoded video over RTP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, vp8

I was able to create an mpeg encoded SRTP stream with ffmpeg, however I need to be able to stream VP8 encoded video.

This is the command I used to create an SRTP stream

```
ffmpeg -re -i BigBuckBunny.mp4 -f rtp_mpegts -acodec mp3 -srtp_out_suite AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 -srtp_out_params <SOME_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE> srtp://127.0.0.1:20000
```

As I ultimately only need to stream video, and not audio, and the file is already a vp8 encoded webm, I assume the option I need to change is the `-f rtp_mpegts` but there doesn't seem to be an option for vp8

Is this possible with FFMEG?

Answer (score 1):

mpegts is an video format for transmission, which is normally bundle with the MPEG-2 codec.

> `-f rtp_mpegts` but there doesn't seem to be an option for vp8

`libvpx` is the ffmpeg encoder ( https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8 )

But if your video exist in VP8 codec, you don't need to recode this video again. You maybe need to rewrap this video into an transport format, which is optimal for your needs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats).

Maybe you should use webM as target container format.

Comment: I assumed that the -f rtp_mpegts flag was specifically for encoding mpeg video for transport over RTP - As this application is for webRTC, which uses containerless video transmission, I was looking for a way (assuming the video is already vp8 encoded with a webM container format) to transmit raw vp8 video through SRTP using ffmpeg